# Redis don't stop or restart on CentOS7

Tags: redis, centos, celery

I've installed Redis version 3.2.12 on one node CentOS 7 of a cluster with Cloudera Manager 6.3 and my redis never stop.
Everything is on default, I just added the password, but that has no effects because I can't restart. Option `daemonize` is `no`

My instalation was:

```
sudo yum -y install redis

sudo service redis start
```

When I type `redis-cli`, CLI starts normally at 127.0.0.1:6379. When I try `shutdown`, the console shows 'not connected', but with `lsof -i :6379` I can identify that some jobs die and return with another PID.
If I try to kill the redis jobs, it always return with another PID.

`service redis stop` Return 'Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop redis.service' but has no effects.

If I try `service redis restart` then `service redis status` it returns:

```
redis.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit redis.service entered failed state.
```

Someone can please help me as a way to debug or understand what is happening? It's my first time with Redis.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how is this related to [celery](/questions/tagged/celery)...
CentOS 7 uses systemd so I would recommend stop using the `service` tool and start using the `systemctl`. First thing you should try is `systemctl status redis` to check the status of the Redis service. If it shows that for whatever reason it is down, then you should either check Redis logs, or use `journalctl` tool to look for system logs created by Redis.

Comment: Hello DejanLekic, thank you for your answer, I tried `systemctl` , but I am facing the same results. I get the complete journal with `grep redis`, but I just can see my installation via yum, my tentatives to stop and the error that I have commented when I tried to restart

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that some installations might have `redis` as the command-line executable while some might have `redis-server`. So, please try one of these commands (one will work depending on the redis package):

```sh
sudo service redis-server restart

# OR

sudo service redis restart
```

If you have a newer Cent OS having `systemctl` installed, then try one of these:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart redis-server

# OR

sudo systemctl restart redis
```